# What it means "Only Local Devices are supported" in XCode Instrumentation

Tags: ios, xcode-instruments

I want to check **Shared Memory** by Instrumentation for my iPhone App. But I cannot start recording . it says **Only Local Devices are supported**[image]

I am using XCode 7.1 and my iPod iOS Version 8.1.3 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shared Memory instrument template only works for OSX applications, [as described in the "Platforms" section of this reference page here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/SharedMemoryInstrument/SharedMemoryInstrument.html).

That's why you're seeing "local devices only".  By "local devices", they mean the MacOS machine you're currently developing on.